# opencl get_local_id or get_global_id in a function called by the kernel

Tags: opencl

Suppose I have a `.cl` like this:

```
void func(whatever){
   int id = get_global_id(0);
   do stuff;
}

__kernel void (whatever){
    func(whatever);
}
```

Will `func` be able to access thread-specific functions like `get_global_id`? It would be annoying to have to manually inline all these functions, and would make the code much less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all functions are able to use work-item functions like `get_global_id()`. The only thing you cannot do in a function that is called from a kernel is declare a function scope local memory array.